# Странное поведение HashMap

Tags: java, java-hashmap

Имеется код:

```
public static Map<String, String> getUsers() {
    Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();
    String path = "users";
    try {
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        try {
            for (String val: lines) {
                String[] field = val.trim().split(" ");
                users.put(field[0], field[1]);
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logs.write("unable to open users file");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return users;
}
```

Данные берутся из файла построчно, а значения разделены запятыми. Затем все заносится в `HashMap`. В чем проблема: `containsKey()` всегда возвращает false для первого элемента `HashMap`, в том числе, если он всего один. Дебаггер показывает, что этот элемент в `HashMap` есть.

```
try {
     if (users.containsKey(credentials[0])) {
         if (users.get(credentials[0]).equals(credentials[1])) {
             logged = true;
             // db = credentials[2];
             writer.println(1);
         } else {
             writer.println(0);
         }
     } else {
         writer.println("Suck");
     }

 } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println(e);
 }
```

Comment: `а значения разделены запятыми`. Внимание вопрос. Где тут `String[] field = val.trim().split(" ");` разделительные запятые?

Comment: А мне ещё интересно, разве у HashMap-а ключи это не результат кэш функций объекта?

Comment: @МаксимДробышев нет. Хеш годится только для относительно быстрого определения того, что объекты разные. Разный хеш => объекты разные. Но обратное не верно. У разных объектов может быть одинаковый хеш. Сначала проверяется хеш, если он совпадает, то вызывается equals для сравнения объектов.

Comment: @Sergey ошибся, разделены пробелами. Почитал, говорят, что надо переопределить equals и hashCod, но я не догоняю как именно

Comment: И что интересно, проблема затрагивает только первый элемент. Всегда. Независимо от его значения

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Все дело было в BOM, который пихался в начало

Comment: Почему не является? Вроде как понятна причина проблемы.